# Get Users and related roles and show on View

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have 3 tables. Users, Roles and RolesToUsers

Here is `User` model:

```
public partial class User
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public User()
    {
        this.UserToRoles = new HashSet<UserToRole>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserToRole> UserToRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Here is `Role` Model:

```
public partial class Role
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Role()
    {
        this.UserToRoles = new HashSet<UserToRole>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserToRole> UserToRoles { get; set; }
}
```

And here is `UserToRole` model:

```
public partial class UserToRole
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Role")]
    public Nullable<int> RoleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

I need to show all Users and related to it Roles.

I write this repo method

```
public List<UserViewModel> GetUsers()
{
    var users = db.Users
        .Include(u => u.UserToRoles.Select(ur => ur.Role))
        .Select(u => new UserViewModel
        {
            UserName = u.Name,
            Roles = u.UserToRoles.Select(ur => ur.Role.Name)
        })
        .ToList();

    return users;
}
```

After it I need to show data from database in this format `Ronald - Admin,User`, where Ronald,etc is Name of Users, after `-` is Roles related to user.

Repo method is working great

And in View I show it using this code.

```js
function GetUsers() {
let url = "/Home/GetUsers";
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var separator = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            var userRow = data[i].UserName + " - " + data[i].Roles.join(", ");

            $('#taskresult3').append(separator + userRow);
            separator = ",";
        }
    }
});
```

Any suggestions or improvements I can do to this code?

Answer (score 1):

[`partial`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) is meant to be used when the class spans multiple files, not when the class is to be extended. If you want to use `virtual` there is no need to mark the class as `partial` unless it really does exist in multiple files (a bad design for the most part anyway, with few good uses). If you want to force the class to be inherited, use `abstract` instead of `partial`.

You can remove the default constructor (and the warning suppression) by using default values:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserToRole> UserToRoles { get; set; } = new HashSet<UserToRole>();
}
```

It is now functionally the same but has less code to maintain.

[Nullable properties can also be defined shorthand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028830/nullableint-vs-int-is-there-any-difference):

```
public class UserToRole
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Role")]
    public int? RoleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int? UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

The `int?` is effectively the same as `Nullable<int>`, it is a little easier on the eyes without having to mentally parse generics.

The last comment is about your repo method. It could be shortened up a little bit:

```
public List<UserViewModel> GetUsers()
{
    return db.Users
        .Include(u => u.UserToRoles.Select(ur => ur.Role))
        .Select(u => new UserViewModel
        {
            UserName = u.Name,
            Roles = u.UserToRoles.Select(ur => ur.Role.Name)
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

Or, if you really want to shorten it up:

```
public List<UserViewModel> GetUsers() => db.Users
                                           .Include(u => u.UserToRoles.Select(ur => ur.Role))
                                           .Select(u => new UserViewModel
                                           {
                                               UserName = u.Name,
                                               Roles = u.UserToRoles.Select(ur => ur.Role.Name)
                                           }).ToList();
```

The only reason I would use the intermediate `users` variable in the method is to do debugging inside the method. You could add a breakpoint on the `return users;` line and debug the value. If you are confident in the operation of the query and the results, shortening it up helps with code maintenance.